# Conversion from UTC to epoch shell script or awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Okay so I've got a few test entries which are running for quite some time now, and I could get the start time from logs

```
Tue Sep 29 09:21:39 UTC 2015: INFO:
Tue Sep 29 09:58:12 UTC 2015: INFO:
Tue Sep 29 09:58:58 UTC 2015: INFO:
Tue Sep 29 10:36:46 UTC 2015: INFO:
Tue Sep 29 11:10:26 UTC 2015: INFO:
Tue Sep 29 11:52:35 UTC 2015: INFO:
Tue Sep 29 12:19:37 UTC 2015: INFO:
Tue Sep 29 13:02:04 UTC 2015: INFO:
Tue Sep 29 13:55:41 UTC 2015: INFO:
Tue Sep 29 13:56:11 UTC 2015: INFO:
Tue Sep 29 13:56:17 UTC 2015: INFO:
Tue Sep 29 13:56:21 UTC 2015: INFO:
```

I am looking to get the time different between subsequent entries, which probably is going to give me the time taken by each test to execute. are there any built-in awk commands that I can make use of to convert these to epoch so I can calculate difference quite easily?

what would be a better approach? single line command would be great.

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: an equivalent unixtime stamp for each entry should be sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert each line into **equivalent unix timestamp**

```
while IFS=: read dt1 dt2 dt3 _; do date -d "$dt1:$dt2:$dt3" '+%s'; done < file.log
1443518499
1443520692
1443520738
1443523006
1443525026
1443527555
1443529177
1443531724
1443534941
1443534971
1443534977
1443534981
```

And to print differential time in seconds between each line use:

```
while IFS=: read dt1 dt2 dt3 _; do
   ts=$(date -d "$dt1:$dt2:$dt3" '+%s')
   [[ $pt ]] && echo $((ts-pt))
   pt="$ts"
done < file.log
```

**Output:**

```
2193
46
2268
2020
2529
1622
2547
3217
30
6
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Single-line perl solution:

```
perl -lane '$p=$d; $d=`date -d "@F[0..3]" +%s`; print $d-$p if $p' file.log
```

Output:

```
2193
46
2268
2020
2529
1622
2547
3217
30
6
4
```

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, do not automatically print the line
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the @F array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace
- `-e` execute the perl code

The first 4 space-delimited fields are sent to `date -d` to return the epochseconds.
Print the difference between the current line `$d` and the previous line `$p`